# load and save richtextBox into database

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, sql-server-2008-r2

First, what datatype I will use to stored richtextBox into database? varbinary?

How I will load and save richtextBox into database?

[image]

This is how I save data with nvarchar data type:

```
using (SqlConnection myDatabaseConnection = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString.ConnectionString))
            {
                myDatabaseConnection.Open();
                using (SqlCommand myCmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into Employee(Lname, Fname, Mname) Values(@Lname, @Fname, @Mname)", myDatabaseConnection))
                {
                    myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fname", FNametextBox.Text);
                    myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lname", LNametextBox.Text);
                    myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mname", MNametextBox.Text);
                    myCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
```

Load data:

```
using (SqlConnection myDatabaseConnection = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString.ConnectionString))
        {
            myDatabaseConnection.Open();
            using (SqlCommand mySqlCommand = new SqlCommand("select Lname, Fname, Mname from Employee", myDatabaseConnection))
            using (SqlDataReader sqlreader = mySqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (sqlreader.Read())
                {
                    LNametextBox.Text = sqlreader["Lname"].ToString();
                    FNametextBox.Text = sqlreader["Fname"].ToString();
                    MNametextBox.Text = sqlreader["Mname"].ToString();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You should use VARCHAR(MAX) or NVARCHAR(MAX) if you're dealing with pure text, like **RichTextBox.Text**:

   ***varchar [ ( n | max ) ]** - Variable-length, non-Unicode string data. n defines the string length and can be a value from 1 through 8,000. max indicates that the maximum storage size is 2^31-1 bytes (2 GB). The storage size is the actual length of the data entered + 2 bytes. The ISO synonyms for varchar are char varying or character varying.*

   Use VARBINARY(MAX) if you're dealing with binary files.
2. Your load and save seems correct :)

Comment: @KarlxSwanovski You should use richTextBox.Rtf to get the text with all formattings